# Is there a Perl module that automatically captures dependencies between Oracle tables based on foreign keys?

Tags: oracle, perl

Does anyone know if there is a Perl module that once given a schema or table, would scan the Oracle database for all related tables based on foreign keys and put them in a hash for further processing?

Something like this for instance:
table 1 = sex, fields sex_id + description
table 2 = person, field person_id + sex_id + other fields

The code would create a hash with among it a key for sex_id, pointing to table sex. 
etc

Answer (score 1):

[DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/~ilmari/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07042/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader.pm) should do the trick, though I have not tried it with Oracle, it is listed as supported in the docs, and worked fine for mysql for me.

Comment: Just my thoughts when I discovered it ;) Feel free to ask if you have any problems